# How to change name of a copied table (during copy-paste method)?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change a name of a table I'm copypasting?

I already have a table I can successfuly copypaste with folllowing procedure

```
Private Sub prev_comments_button_Click()

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Summary").ListObjects("t_sum")
    Dim lr As Integer

    lr = get_tbl_size + 2 ' gets the table size of the current table _
                            and we move by two rows, to indent the copied table

    tbl.Range.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("B" & lr)

End Sub
```

Issue is, sometimes my table indexes glitch out assigning the copied table a name for example t_sum3 instead of t_sum2, which means I can't consistently select the copied table in my worksheet.

> Is it possible to somehow set the copied table name during the
>   copy-paste method?

I'm thinking something akin to

`tbl.Range.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("B" & lr) Name:="t_sum2"`

*^ This however obviously doesn't work*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the listobject which intersects a range - so if we use a range variable for the destination, we can refer to the listobject and rename it, specifically:

```
Private Sub prev_comments_button_Click()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lr As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set tbl = Sheets("Summary").ListObjects("t_sum")

    lr = get_tbl_size + 2 ' gets the table size of the current table _
                            and we move by two rows, to indent the copied table

    Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("B" & lr)
    tbl.Range.Copy rng
    rng.ListObject.Name = "Copied Table"

End Sub
```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that's an already-created procedure i have. (Check the source code). Already stated that works

Comment: nevermind ... my fault, sorry. Thx for clarification anyway. (removed my comment)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to do it. The simplest one I can think of is to assign the second table to a ListObject and change the name of the `ListObject`. Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyTable()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim newTbl As ListObject

    Set tbl = Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")
    tbl.Range.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(1).Range("C20")

    Set newTbl = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(2)
    newTbl.Name = "Gosho"

End Sub
```

However, it would always change the name of the second table in the worksheet, and this is not always the one you are copying.

---

And here is some workaround, setting the specific range of the new table, thus assigning it to the correct `ListObject`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyTable()

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Worksheets(1)
    Dim tblRange As Range: Set tblRange = tbl.Range

    Dim newTbl As ListObject
    Dim newTblRange As Range
    Dim rngToCopy As Range: Set rngToCopy = Range("A20")

    Set newTblRange = wks.Range(rngToCopy, _
                        rngToCopy.Offset(tblRange.Rows.Count, tblRange.Columns.Count))

    tbl.Range.Copy Destination:=rngToCopy        
    Set newTbl = newTblRange.ListObject
    newTbl.Name = "Goshkata be"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah that's kind of the issue. I thought about  listing it as a `Listobject(2)` as well, but it's not necessarily always the second table in my case. Could you perhaps share some other algorhytm you mentioned that can achieve what I desire?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much the same algorhytm Olly above described. I feel like his is a bit easier to comprehend, but either way, both are nice. Thanks for the effort anyways :)